# How do I create a CAB file in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cab

I have an active-x control that I want to run on a web page in ie.

I have written the code for the a-x, and have an msi, using InstallShield.

However when I google, I can find references to using CabWiz.exe (not installed on this pc). or the Microsoft Cabinet Software Development Kit which is no longer supported.

So is a CAB file still the best way to deliver the active x to a users browser, adn if so, how do I create it now?

(Browsers range from ie8 to ie11 for this customer if that matters)